# Show message when method is called when return type is optional

Tags: xcode, swift, methods

```
func bmiMetric(WithWeight w:Double, andHeight h:Double)->(b: Double?, m: String){ 
var bmi = 0.0
var message = "Cant compute BMI"

if h <= 0
{
    return (nil, message)
}

bmi = w/(h*h)

if(bmi > 29){
    message = "Obese"}
else if(bmi  > 25){ message = "Overweight" }
else if(bmi > 18.5){ message = "Normal" }
else{ message = "Underweight" }

return (bmi,message)
```

}

```
var comp = bmiMetric (WithWeight: 75, andHeight: 1.78) 
comp.b
comp.m


print("BMI:",String(bmiMetric(WithWeight: 75, andHeight: 1.78).b!)+".")
```

When I remove the .b! is prints

BMI: (Optional(23.6712536295922), "Normal").

I don't want Optional to print out so what I can do to show the BMI and the message? 
I want it to print :
BMI: (23.6712536295922, "Normal").

P.S
I'm new to Swift so please don't down the answer.

Comment: What is you expected output? Your code prints `BMI: 23.6712536295922.` for me

Comment: I want it to print BMI: (23.6712536295922, "Normal").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you can get `nil` for some input values, I'd suggest you do this instead:

```
if let b = comp.b {
    print("BMI:\(b), \"\(comp.m)\"")
} else {
    print("Cannot calculate BMI")
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I think changing ->(b: Double?, m: String) to ->(b: Double, m: String) would be ever better, no?

Comment: It would be but my professor wanted us to return null and the message if it the result is a negative number. From what I understand "?" means the return is optional and allows null types to be returned?